# How to show drop down list below EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a EditText and one Button for Search, now i want to show list of search result below EditText when click on button,

[image]

when i enter text "abc" and click on search button then drop down should be open below EditText.

need suggestion or sample demo or code.

Edit: It should open drop down which seems like in AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: are you talking about autocomplete

Comment: Yep. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: no autocompletetextview gives the result on every character as we enter in it, but i want results when click on search button.

Comment: What have you tried? That sounds like populating a simple `ListView` with your query results

Answer (score 7):

use AutocompleteTextView, set high treshold "setTreshold()" and call showDropDown() on button click

code update:

```
String[] values = {
    "abc_0", "def_0", "ghi_0",
    "abc_1", "def_1", "ghi_1",
    "abc_2", "def_2", "ghi_2",
    "abc_3", "def_3", "ghi_3",
};

final AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, values);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);
actv.setThreshold(256); // if not enough set Integer.MAX_VALUE
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CharSequence constraint = actv.getText();
        adapter.getFilter().filter(constraint);
        actv.showDropDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: how can i disable dropdown list when i enter the text in AutoComepleteTextView (default behavior ) ?

Comment: yes, setTreshold() disables default behaviour of AutoCompleteTextView, have you ever tried this?

Comment: i think you didn't get the real issue and you have not read the comment below of my question, I don't want result when I entering text, I only want result when i click on search button, and setThresold method limit the text width (minimum character) for displaying result, if we set Thresold Value to 4 then upto 4 character we enter in textview it will not show drop down,

I always give comment after testing the code and you are not... :D :P

Comment: see the updated code, do you think that i wrote it in five minutes?

Comment: ok, thats fine, but I want to manage onclick of searched items, I mean I want to start new activity when I select one of item from searched items,  how can I set onclick listner on searched item ?

Comment: actv.setOnItemClickListener()

Comment: Thank you.Your code helped me a lot to solve my issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/19089277/1767260

Answer (score 1):

you can call `ListView` or `Spinner` on click of search button.. and set values to its `adapter`...

Answer (score 0):

use a list view and set adapter after clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to accomplish this is

- put a textview just below the search which will have width as that of edit text and height wrap content
- set text of search result to it on button click
- when user again try to put anything in search text should get cleared from the text view

Comment: or a list view could be a right option.. you can use its onItemClick then